# Do these brake discs need replacing?

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor

I've had a call from Jaguar Land Rover recommending that all four discs need replacing. I only purchased the car nine months ago.

I agree the pads at 3mm require replacing, but It's hard to tell from the video whether the discs need replacing.

Do they need replacing, or are they trying to get more money out of the service?

Here's the video they have sent https://youtu.be/Zwrw4DPcBYo.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I didn't hear in the video if they measured the disks to see if they could be machined and would still be in spec. You may want to ask them the question of if they can be machined. I don't think the video would give me enough of a warm and fuzzy to say "yah, go ahead with the disks". They should at a minimum be resurfaced, but they should at least give you that option if it is available to you, or tell you why it wouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the small amount of information in the video, I would say that the discs don't NEED replacing.  (This is based purely on visible corrosion)

However, I would agree with the mechanic in the video when he says that he would recommend that the front ones were replaced.  There is quite a wide band of corrosion on the one side of the disc he shows in the video.

The rear disc shown looks fine to me, a small amount of corrosion on the edge is expected.

If at a later date you decide to replace the discs, you will have to replace the pads again, since you shouldn't used old pads with new discs.